# What is the relationship between the side length and the angle of a spherical lune? Is there a sine theorem?

Tags: geometry

[image]

1，Assuming that the red side is a big arc and the blue side is a small arc, what is the relationship between spherical angle A or B and the side length?

2，If both sides are small arcs, what is the relationship between sides and angles? Is there a sine theorem?

3，If all the sides of a spherical triangle are small arcs, what is the relationship between its angle and its side length? Is there a sine theorem?

Why raise this question? Because in the work, we have to solve the length of the small arc between two points on the sphere. The known conditions are the length of a large arc and the spherical angle A or B.

Comment: @E. wei The image is nice. Red line is a longitude through poles is a great circle is easy to get. But what inclination was chosen for small circle. How is it visualized/ graphed?

Comment: @Narasimham The two points A and B, the angle is the dihedral angle, these three factors determine the small circle of blue. The circle is determined by three factors.

Comment: Not quite. If one edge is geodesic it is fully determined. By rotating two planes making a dihedral angle about the dihedral fulcrum edge there are many possibilities. A fourth angle also needs to be specified.

Comment: @Narasimham Is it a theorem that three points on a sphere determine a circle?

Comment: Yes, If three points in spherical coordinates are given $(\theta_1,\phi_1),(\theta_2,\phi_2),(\theta_3,\phi_3) ,$ then $(r,\theta, \phi)$ of small circle center are determined. So a third point on your arcs $ AB_{red}$ and $ AB_{blue}$ are needed to pose your question in completeness.  As a secondary option I would suggest  $ \gamma $ as latitude angle of parallel circle as a property and two points mirroring the Greenwich meridian $\theta=0$ longitude plane for reference to define your "DIANGLE".

Comment: I would answer this question later on if we can be moderate in our comments to the problem under hand.

Comment: @Narasimham My question contains two sides angle A and B, which are the third factor besides the two points.

Comment: Consider a  two steel plates welded at an angle the common line of intersection being along $AB$. Rotation of fulcrum $AB$ produces many "Diangle" intersections with a unit sphere.

Comment: @Narasimham What do you want to explain?

Comment: That the angle between one  plane $AB$ and (plane containing fulcrum passing through sphere center) should also be specified apart from dihedral angle.

Comment: @Narasimham  I already have points A and B and a dihedral angle. I don't need any other conditions anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, [spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry) has a nice Law of Sines (and nice Laws of Cosines) relating the lengths of arcs and the angles bounded by them, but these laws only work for *great* arcs. *Small* arcs defy nice relations, as shown below.

---

First, an observation about the arc-length formula:

$$\text{arc length} = \text{radius}\cdot\text{subtended central angle} \tag{1}$$

We'll find expressions for $\text{radius}$ and $\cos(\text{subtended central angle})$ in terms of a couple of parameters. Unfortunately, because these parameters appear both inside and outside a trig function, we won't be able to solve for them analytically, dashing hopes of a clean, explicit relation between lune angle to arc-lengths. Any work translating between these measurements will require numerical methods (which are beyond the scope of this discussion).

---

Consider an origin-centered sphere of radius $r$, with points $A$ and $B$ on the $xy$-plane; we'll define $C$ as the midpoint of the (minor) great arc $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$, $C^\prime$ as the antipode of $C$, and $M$ as the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$. Specifically, defining $\theta := \frac12 \angle AOB$, we can take
$$A = (r\cos\theta,r \sin\theta,0) \quad B = (r\cos\theta, -r\sin\theta,0) \qquad C = (r,0,0) \quad M = (r\cos\theta,0,0)$$
Also, by $(1)$, we hava
$$|\stackrel{\frown}{ACB}| = 2r\theta \tag{2}$$

Now, consider a plane through $\overline{AB}$ that makes an angle $\phi$ with  the $xy$-plane; write $P$ for the midpoint of (minor) $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$ in that plane. Thus, $\phi = \angle CMP$. Let $O^\prime$ and $p$ be the center and radius of the circle of intersection with plane and sphere; and let $P^\prime$ be the antipode of $P$ in that circle.

Looking at the $xy$-plane "edge-on", with $A$ and $B$ coalescing with $M$, we have this:

[image]

Calculating the [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) of point $M$ with respect to circle in two ways gives
$$\begin{align}|MP||MP'| &= |MC||MC'|  \\
(p+r\cos\theta\cos\phi)(p-r\cos\theta\cos\phi) &= (r+r\cos\theta)(r-r\cos\theta) \\
p^2 - r^2 \cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi &= r^2 \sin^2\theta \\
p^2 &= r^2 \left(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi\right) \tag{2} 
\end{align}$$

So, we have the $\text{radius}$ part of $(1)$. For the $\text{angle}$ part, let's change our view to $\bigcirc ABP$ ...

[image]

... where we see that
$$|\stackrel{\frown}{APB}| = |O'P|\;\angle AO'B =2 p \arcsin\frac{|MA|}{|O'A|}=2p\arcsin\frac{r\sin\theta}{p}  \tag{4}$$
That is, incorporating $(3)$,
$$|\stackrel{\frown}{APB}| = 2r\;\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi}\;\arcsin\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi}}\tag{5}$$
Writing in terms of arccosine will help accommodate major arcs:
$$|\stackrel{\frown}{APB}| = 2r\;\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi}\;\arccos\frac{\cos\theta\cos\phi}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi}}\tag{5'}$$

We're getting closer, but we haven't yet considered the "lune angle", by which we mean the angle made by $\stackrel{\frown}{ACB}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{APB}$ on the surface of the sphere at $A$ (or $B$). Equivalently, this is the angle between tangent vectors to those arcs at $A$. Each such vector must be perpendicular to the normal of the arc's plane (because the vector lies in that plane), and to the vector to $A$ from the arc's center (because tangents are perpendicular to radii); thus, we can calculate those vectors as
$$\begin{align}
v &:= \text{(normal to $\triangle OAB$)}\times \overrightarrow{OA} = (0,0,1)\times A \\
& = (-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0) \\
w &:= \text{(normal to $\triangle O'AB$)}\times \overrightarrow{O'A} = (-\sin\phi,0,\cos\phi)\times (A-O') \\
&= (-r \cos\phi \sin\theta, r \cos\phi \cos\theta, -r \sin\phi \sin\theta)
\end{align}$$
Then, writing $\Phi$ for the lune angle,
$$\cos\Phi = \frac{v\cdot w}{|v||w|}=\frac{r^2\cos\phi}{r^2\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi}}=\frac{\cos\phi}{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta\cos^2\phi}} \tag{6}$$
We can re-write this as
$$\cos^2\phi = \frac{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\Phi}{1-\cos^2\theta\cos^2\Phi} \tag{6'}$$
which allows us to trade the parameter $\phi$ for $\Phi$ in $(5')$

> $$|\stackrel{\frown}{APB}| = \frac{2r\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta\cos^2\Phi}}\;\arccos\left(\cos\theta\cos\Phi\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

Herein, we encounter the problem described in the observation related to $(1)$: because $\Phi$ exists inside and outside of the arccosing in $(\star)$, the equation is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), so we can't solve for the lune angle directly (without appealing to something like [Lambert's $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)).

Now, $(\star)$ doesn't completely answer the question, as it only covers how the (small) arc $\stackrel{\frown}{APB}$ relates to the (great) arc $\stackrel{\frown}{ACB}$. If our lune is bounded by arbitrary arcs $\stackrel{\frown}{APB}$ (which makes lune angle $\Phi$ with the $xy$-plane) and, say, $\stackrel{\frown}{AQB}$ (which makes lune angle $\Psi$ with the $xy$-plane, which is related to the arc length by a counterpart of $(\star)$), then the total lune angle is $\Lambda := \Phi-\Psi$ (or $\Phi+\Psi$, depending upon how you want to assign a sign to $\Psi$). Due to the transcendental nature of $(\star)$, we cannot get a direct relation between $\Lambda$ and the lengths of the bounding arcs. Numerical methods will have to bridge the gap. (Triangles formed of small arcs doesn't get any easier.) $\square$

---

**Addendum: Sanity checks for $(\star)$.**

- If $\Phi=0$, so that $\stackrel{\frown}{APB}$ coincides with $\stackrel{\frown}{ACB}$, then $(\star)$ gives 
  $$|\stackrel{\frown}{APB}| = \frac{2r\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}}\;\arccos\left(\cos\theta\right) = 2r\theta = |\stackrel{\frown}{ACB}| \quad\checkmark$$
- If $\Phi=\pi/2$, so that $\stackrel{\frown}{APB}$ is a semicircle of radius $\frac12|AB| = r\sin\theta$, perpendicular to the plane of $\triangle ABC$, then $(\star)$ gives
  $$|\stackrel{\frown}{APB}| = \frac{2r\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-0}}\;\arccos 0 = \pi r\sin\theta \quad\checkmark$$
- If $\theta = \pi/2$, so that $\overline{AB}$ is a diameter and any arc from $A$ to $B$ must be a great semicircle of radius $r$, then $(\star)$ gives
  $$|\stackrel{\frown}{APB}| = \frac{2r}{\sqrt{1-0}}\;\arccos 0 = \pi r \quad\checkmark$$

Comment: It is suggested to have an illustration.Because I don't understand what angle P is and what angle Q is.

Comment: @E.wei: I have expanded the answer with explanation, slightly-changed notation, and consideration of the proper "lune angle" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to answer, I don't know if it's right.

[image]

$AcB$ is a big arc, $ApB$ is a small arc, capitalized $O$ is the center of sphere, lowercase $o$ is the center of small arc, $∠OMA = π/2$, $∠oMA = π/2$, and the radius of sphere is $R$.

$∠AOB = \frac{ AcB }{ R}$

$ AM = Rsin(\frac{ AcB}{2R})$      (1)

$ OM=Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R})$

Let $φ=∠pMc$

$ Oo=OMsinφ= Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R}) sinφ$

Let the radius of a small circle be r.

$ R^2= r^2+( Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R}) sinφ)^2$

$ r=\sqrt {R^2-(Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R}) sinφ)^2}  $

$∠AoB= \frac{ ApB}{r} =\frac{ ApB/}{\sqrt {R^2-(Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R}) sinφ)^2}}   $

$ AM= \sqrt {R^2-({Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R}) sinφ}) ^2} sin(\frac{ ApB}{2 \sqrt{R^2-({Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R})sinφ}) ^2 } }) $        (2)

Formula (1) equals Formula (2)

$ Rsin(\frac{AcB}{2R})= \sqrt {R^2-({Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R}) sinφ}) ^2} sin(\frac{ ApB}{2 \sqrt{R^2-({Rcos(\frac{ AcB}{2R})sinφ}) ^2 } })  $

or

$Rsin(\frac{ AcB}{2R})= rsin(\frac{ ApB}{2r})$

Comment: @Blue: Your answer seems too complicated. Is my answer correct?

Comment: Your last eqn corresponds to my $(4)$, and your next-to-last to my $(5)$, so I'll say you're correct. :) (I'm a little embarrassed for over-thinking the radius of the smaller circle. That said, I remember having a reason for not writing $1-\cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi$, but I can't now remember just what that reason *was*. :)  My answer goes on to express things in terms of a "lune angle" viewed from the surface of the sphere (which is more consistent with spherical trig's Law of Sines); you seem content with the dihedral angle, which is fine. (Be sure to clarify this kind of thing in the future.)

Comment: The forms are different.

Comment: @Blue: What are the relationship between the sines and the angles of a triangle formed by small arcs?

Comment: I haven't investigated, and probably won't have time for a while. But, as I suggested in the comment above: be clear about what you mean by "angle", either (1) the dihedral angle between the planes containing the arcs, or (2) the angle between tangents to those arcs. (In spherical trig, which deals exclusively in *great arcs*, the two notions are conveniently identical; however, the latter is "the" definition used with general surfaces, so you might want to get used to it.)

Comment: I suppose applying Gauss-Bonnet thm on the Lune helps in  arriving at a Law.

Comment: @Narasimham I suggest you write an answer.