# What is the relationship between $\alpha$, $\beta$, large arc $AB_1$, and small arc $AB_2$?

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is a sphere, the red circle is a great circle, and the blue circle is a small circle.  They intersect at points $A$ and $B$.  At point $A$, the tangents of the great circle and the small circle are $AC$ and $AD$, and their angle is $\alpha$.  The angle between the plane of the great circle and the plane of the small circle is $\beta$.  My question is: What is the relationship between $\alpha$, $\beta$, large arc $AB_1$, and small arc $AB_2$?

Note: $AB_1$ is the arc length of the great circle between $A$ and $B$, and $AB_2$ is the arc length of the small circle between $A$ and $B$. Only when both circles are great circles, $\alpha = \beta$.  Only one circle in this question is the great circle.

The plane of a circle means: any circle has its plane A.  The plane of the circle refers to A.

Comment: $\alpha=\beta$? What are $B_1$ and $B_2$?

Comment: Related: [What is the relationship between the side length and the angle of a spherical lune? Is there a sine theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3179384/409)

Comment: @C.F.G  Note: $AB_1$ is the arc length of the great circle between $A$ and $B$, and $AB_2$ is the arc length of the small circle between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @C.F.G  Only when both circles are great circles, $\alpha = \beta$.  Only one circle in this question is the great circle.

Comment: @C.F.G : No, in general $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not the same. That  would be true if one circle crosses the plane of the other circle at a right angle, but not more generally.

Comment: Maybe something is misleading me. What is the meaning of "the plane of the great circle"? Isn't $AC \in $ this plane? and $AD \in $ other one?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Note that even if \ beta is a right angle, \ alpha is not necessarily a right angle.  Only when both circles are great circles, \ alpha is a right angle when \ beta is a right angle.

Comment: @C.F.G The plane of a circle means: any circle has its plane A.  A is the plane of the circle.

Comment: @C.F.G : Yes, $AC$ and $AD$ are respectively in those two planes. That does not mean that the angle at which they meet is the angle between the two planes. The angle between two planes that intersect in a line is the angle between lines in those two planes that are perpendicular to the line of intersection.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Ahaa.. The angle between $AD$ and $AC$ is the angle that they make in that plane that they lay in. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @C.F.G  $\beta$ is the dihedral angle and $\alpha$ is the tangent angle.

Comment: @MichaelHardy $ \beta$ is the dihedral angle and $\alpha$ is the tangent angle.